# Importing relational diagram from Oracle data modeler to sql server

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have made a relational diagram in Oracle Data Modeler. Now I want to use it in microsoft sql server to write queries on it. How should I do?! I know I have to import it but I couldn't find how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the relational model properties to 'SQL Server' for site type - SQL 2008 is the highest we support at this time.

Now create a physical model, of type SQL Server.

Now export your model to SQL - use this button

[image: Data Modeler DDL Generation Button]

Set your options, and go.

We won't create a database for you. You'll need your own SQL Server already up and running, but then you can have your objects created.